# JDBC multiple connections has same performance as single connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I wrote a simple java program to use JDBC to run 20 queries to fetch data from a view

```
int connectionSize = 10;
    ds.init(connectionSize, settings);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    try {
        stopwatch.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String sql = String.format("select * from viewA where userId in (%s)", randomUserIds(5));
                    PreparedStatement ps = null;
                    Connection conn = null;
                    try {
                        while ((conn = ds.getConnection()) == null) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
                        }
                        logger.info("conn: " + conn.toString());
                        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ps.executeQuery();
                        ps.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (conn != null) {
                            ds.returnConnection(conn);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        boolean finished = executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        stopwatch.stop();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Query Complete in " + stopwatch);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

e.g. `select * from ViewA where userId in (random few user Ids)`

1. I used a single connection, and inside a for loop executed the 20 queries in a sequential way
2. I set up 10 connections in a pool and running the 20 queries in 10 threads

I expected the second approach would use less time to finish the 20 queries, but after testing, the results show me these two approaches return similar time consumption.

I can confirm when I was running the second approach, it created 10 sessions in db.

Is the second approach supposed to give a better performance than the first one? What would be the problem to make the second performance same as the first one?

Comment: There are a lot of different factors, for example: how much time you spend on creating threads, connection pool initialization, create session, etc. But as a developer you shouldn't guess, just trace/profle it and you will get real picture

Comment: What is `ds`???

Comment: @Andreas `OracleDataSource` class initializing with `ds` ie `OracleDatasource ds = new OracleDataSource();`

Comment: Thanks @Joe, yes. it is OracleDataSource Andreas

Comment: Really?!? That's weird, because the code in the question has e.g. `ds.init(connectionSize, settings);`, but `OracleDataSource` does not have an `init()` method.

Comment: Which one are you using? [`oracle.jdbc.datasource.OracleDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/datasource/OracleDataSource.html), [`oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html), or [`oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/replay/OracleDataSource.html)?

Comment: actually I wrote my own dataSource using DriverManager.getConnection() to create multiple connections in thread safe collections.

Comment: Also tried with oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource, they return the same results. P.S. (conn.toString() with different ram address. the dataSource returned different connctions, isit?)